# SOIC8 marking (direction)

Tags: soldering, packages

I received some ICs in the package SOIC8. Usually the packages have some indicator where the 1 Pin is. This does not. 
I found the chip soldered on a board on the internet and with the marking on it I can guess the direction of the package.

[image]

Is there a better way to determine the direction?

Comment: Do you have a picture of it? Some ICs will have a chamfered edge to help indicate where pin 1 is

Comment: Or better yet, just look at the part datasheet. They usually have clear pinout explanation.

Comment: The pinout is in the datasheet, but the symbol is very generic and does not correspond to the marking on the chip
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TJA1020.pdf

Comment: I do not know what you mean. On page 17 it clearly shows where pin 1 is located. The body is not symmetrical, on one side the chamfer is much bigger to indicate pin 1.

Comment: Also, how on earth is that a TSSOP-20?!

Comment: My mistake. The TSSOP is another part of the board. This is clearly a SO.
I did not notice the asymmetrical marking. This solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, a picture makes this much clearer.

[image]

When there is no identification 'dot' there will often be a chamfered edge on the side where pin 1 is. Facing the chamfered side towards you, pin 1 will be on the left had side. (Pin 1 is indicated by the red arrow)

[image]

This is quite common in some packages like the SOIC family.

Answer (score 4):

Usually references printed on top aren't the best methods for recognition of PIN1 location. The print disappears sometimes or can be removed. Normally you will have a deep dip, cut corner, U-shaped dip or similar. 
In your case the datasheet shows PIN orientation by chamfer on top face.
The datasheet picture:

[image: Front marking]

And your picture:
[image: FrontReal]

PIN1 (as on the picture): bottom - left.